# How to override pushd's and popd's automatic call to dirs?

Tags: bash, built-in, bash-function

My `bash` (4.1) directory stack usually has a dozen or more entries.  I wanted to replace the output of `dirs` with [`dirs -v`](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins), so I would never have to play "guess the magic number" with `pushd` again.

### My Partial Solution

I replaced `dirs` with a function that executed `dirs -v` using [`command`](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

```bash
dirs()
{
    # "command" builtin prevents infinite recusion by suppressing lookup
    # of function and alias names.
    command dirs -v "${@}"
}
```

(Update:  At [pneumatics' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715775/4116239), I now use [`builtin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) instead of `command`.  It doesn't solve this problem, but it's slightly safer.)

`dirs` output was now readable, but **`pushd` and `popd` still produced the old vomit-of-slashes**:

```
$ pushd ~/just/one/more/and/ill/quit/i/promise
~/just/one/more/and/ill/quit/i/promise ~/tmp/bash/bash-4.1...
may/give/rise/to/dom /oh/no/not/again /var/adm/log /omg/wt...
va/lang ~/doc/comp/java/api/java/util/regex barf barf barf...
```

I got the same (lack of) result after replacing my `dirs` function with an alias:

```bash
alias dirs='command dirs -v "${@}"'
```

### The Workaround

I eventually got the output I wanted by overriding `pushd` and `popd` as well:

```bash
pushd()
{
    command pushd "${@}" >/dev/null &&
      dirs
}
# popd is similar.
```

This works, but it requires overriding *three* builtins instead of one.  Also, this could be an imperfect impersonation of `pushd` and `popd` in some corner case I haven't thought of.  I'd rather override `dirs` only.

### My Question

**Why didn't overriding `dirs` work?**  According to `bash`'s `man` page, under both `pushd` and `popd`:

> If the `pushd` command is successful, a `dirs` is performed as well.

So why did `pushd` and `popd` appear to invoke the builtin `dirs` instead of the function or the alias?

#### Footnote about the `bash` Documentation

The paragraphs saying "a `dirs` is performed as well" are missing from the [`bashref.*` online manual](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins), but they appear in the `man` pages `bash.*` and `builtins.*`.  Both my `bash` 4.1 docs and the current 4.4 docs are inconsistent in the same manner, which suggests that 4.4 (if I had it) would behave the same.

Comment: Because they hard call the built in. See http://web.mit.edu/~ecprice/athena_bash/builtins/pushd.def

Comment: @bishop:  Ugh, I was afraid it would be something like that.  Do you know if this is the usual way a `bash` builtin calls another builtin --- going straight for the C function without searching `$PATH`, shell functions, or aliases?  (Obviously, I expected `pushd` to look up `dirs` as if it had been typed on the command line, but now I can't tell if my expectation was reasonable.)  If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my reading of the [bash source code](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash), both [`pushd`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/pushd.def#n172) and [`popd`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/pushd.def#n318) call the [`dirs`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/pushd.def#n403) builtin itself (without any args), rather than consulting defined aliases and functions.

While it seems rare that a builtin leverages external functionality, when a builtin *does need* external functionality, calling another builtin seems precedent. For example, when `pushd` changes directory, [it calls the `cd` builtin](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/pushd.def#n299). Or when `declare` needs to type cast a variable, [it calls the `set` builtin](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/declare.def#n260).

How to work around this? Well, one could recompile bash from source: it'd be trivial to have `pushd` and `popd` pass the `-v` argument. One could also petition bash upstream to add an environment variable that defined the default `dirs` options when used as a helper to `pushd`/`popd`. But it seems like the quickest userland solution is as you've done: just override all three.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `builtin` instead of `command`. I think this is what you're after, overrides to `pushd` and `popd`, while leaving `dirs` as-is.

```
pushd(){ builtin pushd "$@" >/dev/null && dirs -v; }
popd() { builtin popd "$@" >/dev/null  && dirs -v; }
```

Comment: `builtin` is an improvement over `command`, but in this case only a slight one.  Since `pushd` and `popd` _can't_ be implemented as external binaries or scripts, they're unlikely to appear in `$PATH`...  but I suppose some other executable could just happen to have one of those names.  It doesn't explain why overriding `dirs` alone didn't do the job, which was my primary question.

Comment: I hate to give a tautological answer, but pushd and popd are calling builtin dirs, because that's what they're doing. I don't think you can prevent that from happening. You can swallow the output, but they are calling bulitin dirs, regardless of what functions or aliases are defined in the environment. That's what `builtin` is there for, to allow you to find your rock of `builtin`-ness in the swirl of crazy override functions and aliases!

Comment: I looks like that's the case...  The existence of `command` (and now `builtin`) is a large part of why I expected the normal command-name lookup would happen: I _hadn't_ used the special builtins that exist to prevent it.

Comment: I switched from `command` to `builtin`, as you suggested.  I had to keep the `&&` command separator though (instead of `;`), because `dirs` output should only appear if the `pushd` or `popd` was successful.

Comment: oh, yes, that's a good point. I usually run `set +o errexit`, and didn't notice that problem, I'll edit.